# What is the difference between sim operator and network operator

Tags: android

I was going through the Telephony manager API in android
and came across these two functions :

getNetworkOperatorName : Returns the alphabetic name of current registered operator.
getSimOperatorName() : Returns the Service Provider Name

My understanding is not so clear on these terms.
What is the difference betwen these two?
Please give some examples if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The network operator is the carrier. The one that physically delivers the data.

The SIM operator is the provider of your data. You probably have only one provider associated with your SIM card. But if you travel around the world then you will encounter many different carriers.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference of obtaining information from the card.

`Network  operator code` will return data only if has connection with gsm network.

`Sim Card operator code` will always return value, even if You are in flight mode.